# Differences in Diamond and Polyethylene despite both having carbon atoms?

Tags: material-science, physical-chemistry

Diamond and Polyethylene both have Carbon atoms joined by strong covalent bonds. But their properties are different, with Diamond being very hard and has a high melting temperature, and Polyethylene having a low hardness and low melting temperature.

I am wondering, how are these differences possible?

Comment: for polyethylene https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene for diamond https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond  The links have images on the right of the structure. (for diamond it is in a link)

Comment: and they have different chemical formulas, just wait till you hear about graphite

Comment: OP this thread is certainly useful for you https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/159394/if-bond-types-are-in-reality-intermixed-how-come-different-bonds-form-completel also would be better to compare graphite, diamond, fullerenes as for the elemental composition it for all the same, just carbon. PE has its own, so falls in the O2 H20 case of the answer below.

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

Polyethylene also has a lot of hydrogen, and the bonds are different (long chains, and not a 3D lattice).
That's kinda like asking why water and $O_2$ are so different when they both have oxygen.  It's the wonders of chemistry.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Polyethylene consists of long chains of carbon atoms, each with two hydrogen atoms bonded to it, and an additional hydrogen atom at each end. These may be very long in terms of the numbers of carbon atoms but the limitations on their lengths and the random orientations limit the strength and stiffness of the material. When subjected to stress, molecules slide over one another, only held together by their intermolecular forces.  If it was possible to make a large piece of polyethylene with molecules of millimetre length and uni-directional, its strength would be very large indeed.

Diamonds on the other hand approximate to single crystals consisting of carbon atoms in a uniform three dimensional lattice, so fracturing a diamond involves breaking the chemical bonds. In fact fracturing a single crystal diamond can only be done by breaking the chemical bonds, and these are extremely strong.